# Possible reactions due to antiproton-proton collisions

Tags: particle-physics, collision, antimatter

When an antiproton collides with a proton, then "all" reactions/channels are possible, right? Only constrained by the used energy and sure, some channels are more likely than others but in principle, all are possible?

Answer (score -1):

The vast majority of collisions put most of the energy into the production of photons. However,the original parts of the proton and antiproton that did not annihilate will combine with the products of the annihilation and will generate a stream of multiple outgoing particles.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is a bit more precise: Are there channels which are not available or are there even "forbidden" channels?

Comment: Well there is a limit placed on the mass of particles produced by the combined mass of the proton antiproton pair. Therefore the only forbidden reactions will be those that violate energy conservation (or any other conservation laws).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation Photons do not dominate.